# Embedding HTML5 video player in Facebook for Testing

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm looking to embed an HTML5 video player in the Facebook feed, similar to what sites like YouTube and Vimeo do already, using the "text/html" tag:

```
<meta property="og:type" content="video">
  <meta property="og:video:url" content="...">
  <meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="...">
  <meta property="og:video:type" content="text/html">
```

As I understand this requires whitelisting from Facebook currently, and when I use the same tags I just see a white box with a "Download File" link.

This is expected, however as my site has not launched yet and I do not know the final URL, I'm not able to apply for whitelisting, currently I just need to be able to demo this behavior.

Is there any way of enabling this feature in test just to show how it would work and begin developing the Facebook integration before asking about whitelisting?

Comment: No, there is not. And your chances of getting whitelisted are likely really, really small as well (read: most likely not gonna happen), considering the security implications of embedding custom HTML5 content.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.