# Embed HTML5 video into Facebook

Tags: html, facebook, html5-video, facebook-opengraph

Isn't it possible to embed a HTML5/JS code iframe into Facebook through open graph anymore?

After searching through stackoverflow most of the questions are outdated and don't explain how to achieve this.

The code I am using is this one provided from Kaltura http://player.kaltura.com/modules/KalturaSupport/components/share/Share.html

```
<!-- Facebook Open Graph tags -->
<meta property="og:title" content="Kaltura Player: Share Plugin example" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://player.kaltura.com/modules/KalturaSupport/components/share/Share.html">
<meta property="og:description" content="Kaltura Player: Share plugin demonstrates the ease of which social share can be configured with the kaltura player toolkit." />
<meta property="og:type" content="video" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://cdnbakmi.kaltura.com/p/243342/sp/24334200/thumbnail/entry_id/1_sf5ovm7u/version/100003/width/400" />
<meta property="og:image:seucre_url" content="https://cdnsecakmi.kaltura.com/p/243342/sp/24334200/thumbnail/entry_id/1_sf5ovm7u/version/100003/width/400" />


<!-- Facebook iframe embed  -->
<meta property="og:video:url" content="https://cdnapisec.kaltura.com/p/243342/sp/24334200/embedIframeJs/uiconf_id/28685261/partner_id/243342?iframeembed=true&playerId=kaltura_player&entry_id=1_sf5ovm7u">
<meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="https://cdnapisec.kaltura.com/p/243342/sp/24334200/embedIframeJs/uiconf_id/28685261/partner_id/243342?iframeembed=true&playerId=kaltura_player&entry_id=1_sf5ovm7u&">
<meta property="og:video:type" content="text/html">
<meta property="og:video:width" content="560">
<meta property="og:video:height" content="395">
```

The issue here is Kaltura is able to execute it's HTML5, a video player in this case, but if I modify the "og:video:secure_url" with another CDN the player doesn't play.

It looks like it's a whitelist Facebook has with Kaltura, YouTube, Twitch TV, Vimeo, SoundCloud (with special open graph audio), etc **or something I am doing wrong**

My question is, does the secure_url HTML need some special configuration? or do I have to apply to Facebook whitelist and in that case how can I do that? Has it to be done trough this application? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/submission-process

These are other stackoverflow questions I have checked but they are outdated or don't fully explain the process.

- [Where do you whitelist your domain on Facebook for video embeds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7518833/where-do-you-whitelist-your-domain-on-facebook-for-video-embeds)
- [How is SoundCloud embedding an HTML5/JS widget on Facebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22751484/how-is-soundcloud-embedding-an-html5-js-widget-on-facebook)
- [Embedding HTML5 video player in Facebook for Testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32606319/embedding-html5-video-player-in-facebook-for-testing)
- [Embedding HTML5 content into Facebook wall posts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6746671/embedding-html5-content-into-facebook-wall-posts)

Comment: Facebook is testing this with a limited set of partners. There is no way to apply to become one.

Comment: That's what I have read in some places, do you have a source for that? I cant find any official update on this

Comment: There is no official documentation or anything like that. But FB employees repeatedly have stated the same in the FB developers group.